# Illustrator script: How to style when injecting text?

Tags: javascript, jsx, adobe-illustrator

I'm looping through JSON data to inject text into an existing text block in Illustrator CC.

I'd like to style each word when I inject it (some words will be a certain color).

```
  textArt = doc.textFrames[0];
  for(var i = 0; i < myJSONData.length; i++){
    textArt.contents = textArt.contents + ' ' + datum.text;
    // Something here to style the word "testing"
  }
```

I can do this after the fact by looping through the text and applying a character style, like so:

```
for ( i = 0; i < doc.textFrames.length; i++ ) {
   for ( j = 0; j < textArt.words.length; j++) {
      word = textArt.words[j];
      doc.characterStyles.getByName("bolded").applyTo ( word );
   }; 
};
```

But how can I do it when adding it to a text block in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a new word object instead of just adding new text to contents:

```
var textArt = doc.textFrames[0];
var newWord = textArt.words.add(' new text');
doc.characterStyles.getByName("bolded").applyTo(newWord);
```